# Google Chrome breaks network connection when JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, networking, tcp, google-chrome

I have this strangest problem and I can't debug it.

I am writing a heavy JavaScript application, which spawns a popup when user uploads a file. The actual file transfer happens in the popup, which is set to be the FORM submit target.

Works in all browsers, there are no javascript errors. However, in Google's Chrome browser, when form is submitted, my entire network card device (inside my PC) gets blocked - as in - no  connetion with outside world . The only way of fixing it is to Disable the hardware device, then enable it back.

I've seen Chrome acting like this at other times. It is impossible to debug this, as there are no errors, internet just stops working. Please don't tell me it's a driver issue :) It's most likely some JavaScript code that triggers something in Chrome to go beserk.

Does anyone know what gives? I am on chrome v. 3.0.195.27

Answer (score 2):

For an application to cause such a problem, where if you close it, your device is still disabled, I'm sorry, but it's a driver issue :)

To the point, can you monitor the network traffic (use [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx), or Resource Monitor in Windows 7, or your favorite sniffer) to find the exact point where the error occurs? You're looking for a graph with a downward slope or a flat line.

You can report a bug to Google, but unless you can recreate the behavior on another machine, I doubt anyone will handle it.

Comment: Yes, it's disabled even when I close the application. I will try the Monitor, thank you for the tip!

Comment: An application could damage network driver on purpose and it would still remain damaged after the application is closed, but it's clearly not the case here.

Comment: Conceivably, an application can do everything - up to, and including formatting your drive :) Somehow, I doubt Google is in the business of causing damage (I mean, their motto is "do no evil") :)

Comment: FYI - I've seen exactly the same thing, i.e. Google Chrome killing off my network adapter. Only seems to have been a problem in Windows 7 - I've stopped using Chrome now, and things are back to normal.

Comment: @Mark, which version of Chrome? Did you report a bug to Google?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you wanted to do something like that with Javascript in browser, you couldn't do it. Of course there's a small chance that there's somekind of bug in Chrome which get's triggered by JS but I don't think so.

Maybe try over at superuser.com . Your question isn't really programing related.

Comment: You are right, not very programing related, my bad. I just hoped programers at this site would have seen such a behaviour before me.

Comment: @Gotys, don't worry too much about it, questions in the wrong place get migrated to where they belong eventually :)

Comment: bdonlan, yes. Still haven't finished my morning coffee =(